# How To Prevent - Last Modified Date/Time - to not show on Pages but only Posts

Tags: wordpress, last-modified

I have created a separate plugin for WordPress (that's usually called the site-specific plugin) where I added a function to display the last modified date and time. Well, it works good but I don't want to display the same for PAGES but only for Posts.

What should I modify in this code?

```
    function wpb_last_updated_date( $content ) {
$u_time = get_the_time('U'); 
$u_modified_time = get_the_modified_time('U'); 
if ($u_modified_time >= $u_time + 86400) { 
$updated_date = get_the_modified_time('F jS, Y');
$updated_time = get_the_modified_time('h:i a'); 
$custom_content .= '<p class="last-updated"><b>Last updated on</b> '. $updated_date . ' at '. $updated_time .'</p>';  
} 

    $custom_content .= $content;
    return $custom_content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpb_last_updated_date' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check which page is being displayed with these conditions:

```
is_page()     //For pages
is_single()   //for posts
is_singular() //for posts AND pages
is_category() //for categories
is_tag()      //for tags
is_404()      //for 404 page
```

Try putting code below which have condition to add custom content to only the posts:

```
function wpb_last_updated_date( $content ) 
{
      $u_time = get_the_time('U'); 
      $u_modified_time = get_the_modified_time('U');

      if ($u_modified_time >= $u_time + 86400) 
      { 
           $updated_date = get_the_modified_time('F jS, Y');
           $updated_time = get_the_modified_time('h:i a'); 
           if(is_single()) 
           {
                 $custom_content .= '<p class="last-updated"><b>Last updated on</b> '. $updated_date . ' at '. $updated_time .'</p>';  
           }
      }
      $custom_content .= $content;
      return $custom_content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpb_last_updated_date' );
```

For a more complete list of template tags check visit:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page

Answer (score 0):

Hi is_page() function can be used to check whether a page is post or page, so we can use that condition.

```
function wpb_last_updated_date( $content ) 
{
      $u_time = get_the_time('U'); 
      $u_modified_time = get_the_modified_time('U');

      if ($u_modified_time >= $u_time + 86400) 
      { 
           $updated_date = get_the_modified_time('F jS, Y');
           $updated_time = get_the_modified_time('h:i a'); 
           if(!is_page()) 
           {
                 $custom_content .= '<p class="last-updated"><b>Last updated on</b> '. $updated_date . ' at '. $updated_time .'</p>';  
           }
      }
      $custom_content .= $content;
      return $custom_content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpb_last_updated_date' );
```

Or you can check the current post type and do this, below code will do the filter only for post type 'post'.

```
   function wpb_last_updated_date( $content ) 
{
      $u_time = get_the_time('U'); 
      $u_modified_time = get_the_modified_time('U');

      if ($u_modified_time >= $u_time + 86400) 
      { 
           $updated_date = get_the_modified_time('F jS, Y');
           $updated_time = get_the_modified_time('h:i a'); 
global $post;
      if ($post->post_type == 'post')
           {
                 $custom_content .= '<p class="last-updated"><b>Last updated on</b> '. $updated_date . ' at '. $updated_time .'</p>';  
           }
      }
      $custom_content .= $content;
      return $custom_content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpb_last_updated_date' );
```

Comment: Help appreciated! Thanks :-D